# Saving an xml document results in corrupt file

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I have a question on how to save an xmldoc as a word file. I want to open the word file, do some manipulation on the undelying xml structure using the xmldocument class and then resave it back to the word file. This is what im currently doing:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"E:\HelloWorld.docx", true))
                {
                   MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                   var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                   using (Stream partStream = part.GetStream())
                   using (XmlReader partXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(partStream))
                     xmlDoc.Load(partXmlReader);
                   //xml node manipulation here

                   xmlDoc.Save(@"E:\HelloWorld.docx");
                 }
```

This results in a corrupt document however. What is the proper way to do this functionality?

Comment: Could you please comment on what is corrupt and what you expect: HelloWorld.Test will be an XML file, not docx, so is XML invalid XML or is HelloWorld.docx corrupt or you expect HelloWorld.Test to be an worrd document?

Comment: sry that was a typo. I am trying to open a docx, use the xmldoc to do extract the xml structure, modify it and then write it back to another docx file. so HelloWorld should be a docx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenXML document is more than just a XML file (actually, it's a ZIP archive containing several files, XML files among them).

What you should do is to modify your `WordprocessingDocument` and then save it (which is done automatically at the end of the `using` block), not save the XML file that represents part of the document:

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    using (Stream partStream = mainPart.GetStream())
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        using (XmlReader partXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(partStream))
            xmlDoc.Load(partXmlReader);

        //xml node manipulation here

        partStream.Position = 0;

        using (XmlWriter partXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(partStream))
            xmlDoc.Save(partXmlWriter);
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure if its this method or something wrong with my xml manipulation code thats at fault since i cant see any changes. basically in the manipulation part, i am trying to delete several runs from the document but they still show up by the end.

Comment: @JohnBaum, this code works for me. Are you sure you're using it exactly as I wrote it (reset the `Position` of the stream and then write the XML to it)? And we can't help you with your code unless you how it to us. You should probably ask another question and put your code there.

Comment: Seems correct to me. Have you debugged it to see whether it actually removed the nodes you think it should be removing?

Comment: how would i debug that? the nodes are being removed from the parent if thats what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully performed the manipulation you can later save back to file using [`Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close.aspx) on your `wordDoc` variable. The MSDN states that this also saves the content.

Comment: Then you probably didn't actually modify the document, see my answer.

Comment: HOw can i make sure the document was modified?

Answer (score 0):

docx will be an XML file, not DOCX.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
... 
xmlDoc.Save(@"E:\HelloWorld.docx");
```

What you want is either create new WordprocessingDocument or update existing one with the XML you've modified. Something along the lines

```
using (StreamWriter sw =
    new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        xmlDoc.Save(sw);
    }
```

See more samples in the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.document.aspx

Comment: does this create a docx file with my changes? where does it create it?

Comment: MSDN sample shows/explains how to do it, but see svick's answer.