# How to render data set data to word (docx) file with template?

Tags: c#, .net

In my c# .net (win form) project I have to many template word file with content and tables. I want fill this word file with my database data by using ms word bookmark or field. What tools I can use for this issue?
Point: this tools must fill my nested table in word with appropriate template definition. 
Any ideas are welcome. 
I know aspose.word but it is not free, I looking to find free one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1. OpenXml
2. DocX

I have used OpenXml in past and is quite handy.

I don't have code for the same, however here are few links from stackoverflow itself
[Saving an xml document results in corrupt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842376/saving-an-xml-document-results-in-corrupt-file)
[Save modified WordprocessingDocument to new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818160/save-modified-wordprocessingdocument-to-new-file)

For docx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra